# Android studio 3.5 for Mac OSX Catalina is crashing on the index process

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

When I open my project, in the index process the application is quitting and show me this error, I tried:

- Invalidating and restarting,
- Removing the Iml file
- Adding this configuration to VMOptions file:

> -Dsun.font.layoutengine=icu

- Reseting the project and downloading it again
- Formatting the computer
- Changing my branch
- Erasing Gradle cache file

But they didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Kindly Update your mac OS to 10.15.3 which is latest for now and update your android studio and emulator updates.